# get total pages number of webpage python

Tags: python, selenium

I read a lot on StackOverflow but couldn't find anything that was apt for my situation.

So, I am trying to open a website and search for a keyword. I want to go on every page and get the price. I will do this for all the pages.

Initially, I tried clicking on the next button but the 'Next button' on this website doesn't get disabled. For example, if there are 15 pages, so on the 15th page the next page button should get disabled, but I can click on it infinite times. After the 15th page, on clicking on it, it just shows the 15th page only.

So I am getting the totalpages count and using while loop like follows: Can anyone help me syntactically? I did the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#open a website and search a keyword

from  selenium import webdriver
driver =webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://www.insight.com/en_US/search.html')


list=['printer','printer cartridges','printer accessories']
for searchelement in list:
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("search-tab-banner-box-input")
inputElement.clear()
inputElement.send_keys(list)

wait( driver, 30 ).until( EC.visibility_of_element_located( (By.ID, "search-tab-banner-box-input") ) ).send_keys(Keys.ENTER )
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.TAB )

i=1
#Get total number of pages in search result and navigate through
 # I want to do something like this. this is my logic not real code
totalpages= enumerate(driver.gettotalnumber of pages)
while (i<totalpages)

            driver.find_element_by_class_name( "ion-chevron-right" ).click()
            i+=1
#Get total number of pages
```

How can I get the total number of pages in that variable?

Comment: Your `while` statement should not be indented

Comment: Oh! I am sorry , it was a typo here.

Comment: `driver.gettotalnumber of pages`?

Comment: How about using `page_source` to compare the html of the pages

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000: that's my logic. Not the real code

Comment: When you `search a keyword` you start getting auto-suggestions, how can you `go on every page and get the price`?

Comment: @DebanjanB: i just want to know how should I get total numberof pages in that variable.

Comment: `total numberof pages`from where? Are you trying to count the number of Auto-suggestions?

Comment: @DebanjanB: I am trying to send some searchwords from a list into the searchbox of the website.Then retrieve the total number of pages and iterate till last pag. Please see my code. Thanks. The next button doesn't get disabled so I am getting the total number of pages in a variable and run the loop for true value till that variable

Comment: See doing `inputElement.send_keys(list)` is as good as doing `inputElement.send_keys(['printer', 'printer cartridges', 'printer accessories'])` This search won't fetch you any suggestion. Again if you try to `inputElement.send_keys("printer")` you get auto-suggestions. So you have click on a suggestion, not `Keys.TAB`. Again, `if there are 5 pages` I don't see the `next page button` on page 5. Am I missing something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151738/discussion-between-programmer-and-debanjanb).

Comment: @DebanjanB: There is next button tag on top left corner

Comment: Unfortunately that `next button tag on top left corner` takes us to the previous page i.e `Page 4`

Answer (score 0):

```
price='0'  
while True:
     if price!=driver.find_element_by_class_name("prod-price"):
           driver.find_element_by_class_name( "ion-chevron-right" ).click()
     else:
           break
     i+=1
     price=driver.find_element_by_class_name("prod-price")

#Get total number of pages
print('the total number of pages is ', i)
```

This should work. It compares the price of the pages.

Comment: Well I want to know how should I implement>>>>>>>>>>>>>totalpages= enumerate(driver.gettotalnumber of pages)

Comment: `gettotalnumber` is not a function

Comment: `i` will have the amount of pages

Comment: Yep thats what my question is! How do I get the total number of pages on that website upon sending those keywords into the searchbar.

Comment: I edited the answer. Now it just gets the number of pages and prints it. This code will just get the number pages, not the rest of the stuff

Comment: Hi, I want to get total number of pages available on the webpage. not the ones that I am counting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151745/discussion-between-programmer-and-whackamadoodle3000).